# custom attribute displaying but is not saving in magento 2 admin customer creation form

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

i have created new customer attribute in my magento 2 environment [image: field is added]

field is added the data in that filed is not saving.i am getting error as something went wrong while saving data.there is no good tutorials i could find to add new attribute.please help with this.

i have followed this code

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/magento-2-add-custom-attribute-in-customer-registration-form

Answer (score 2):

Customer Registration Custom attribute value create in admin and save

**1. Text Field**

**2. Drop Down Field**

**3. Date Field**

**Using** `UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php

namespace {CompanyName}\{ModuleName}\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
/* add this */
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) 
        {
            // For Text field
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                    'attribute_title',                    
                    [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'input' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Attribute Title',
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 1000,
                        'position' => 1000,
                        'system' => 0,
                    ]
                );
            $attribute_title = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_title')
                ->addData(
                    ['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]);

            $attribute_title->save();

            //Add field Drop Down for Yes/No
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                    'is_attribute',                    
                    [
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'label' => 'Is Attribute',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'default' => '1',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 1000,
                        'position' => 1000,
                        'system' => 0,
                    ]
                );
            $is_attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_attribute')
                ->addData(
                    ['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]);

            $is_attribute->save();

            // For Date And Time field
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'custom_date',                    
                [
                    'label' => 'Custom Date',
                    'type' => 'datetime',
                    'input' => 'date',
                    'frontend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime',
                    'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime',
                    'validate_rules' => '{"input_validation":"date"}',
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1000,
                    'position' => 1000,
                    'system' => 0,
                ]
            );
            $custom_date = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_date')
                ->addData(
                    ['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]);
                // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
            $commenced_business->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data save will not happen by itself you need to set data into attribute.
If its part of customer Interface
For example

```
$attribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('client_dn');
if ($attribute)
{
    $customer->setValue("hi");
}

if you are saving using customer object
$customer->setData('client_dn', 'Hi');
```